# Oracle Linux VM on Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have downloaded [32bit Virtual Box version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) and [32bit Oracle Linux VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/enterprise-linux-090498.html). This my basic settings:
[image]

But then I'm catching:

```
This kernel requires an x68-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate your CPU.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install 64-bit (x64) OS on a 32-bit guest. Either define the VM Guest as 64-bit or install 32-bit operating system on it.

Comment: How can I define VM Guest as 64-bit?

Comment: From top of my head, go to settings -> general and change "version" to 64-bit variant. I don't have vbox available right now so I can't verify. 64-bit guests require hardware support on host, so confirm that you have it enabled. Otherwise switch to 32-bit guest - i.e. download another image/installation media for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **Intel VT-x/AMD-V** from BIOS,Please refer http://hereirestinremorse.wordpress.com/virtualbox/this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-unable-to-boot-please-use-a-kernel-appropriate-for-your-cpu/ for your reference.